# 'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I try to use with "else" command but I get the foloowing error:

**'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

My code is:

```
if "zz"=="TRUE" (
        copy /a zz + /a ee=/a zz
    ) 
    else (
        copy /a e + /a %TMP%=/a e
    )
```

What the problem?

Comment: I am not recognizing the language I am afraid (so cannot edit on my own), can you add a tag to attract users who are familiar with it?

Comment: "else" may not be recognised simply because these are language specific - you don't specify which language, which environment you use

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The `else` needs to be on the same "line" <sup>(a)</sup> as the `if`. Remove the new-line before the `else` like so:

```
if "zz"=="TRUE" (
    copy /a zz + /a ee=/a zz
) else (
    copy /a e + /a %TMP%=/a e
)
```

Please also note that `"zz"=="TRUE"` will never evaluate to `true` - I suspect you meant `"%zz%"=="TRUE"`?

---

<sup>(a)</sup>: This isn't always a good description, though it's what the Microsoft documents use. Same *command* may have been better, and putting `)` and `else` on a different line breaks it into *two* commands.

Comment: This is a rather liberal interpretation of the phrase "same line" but it's what I expect from `cmd` :-) +1 for the right answer, if not quite perfect phrasing.

Comment: @paxdiablo It's not the best phrasing, but it's taken straight from `IF /?`. Specifically, "The ELSE clause must occur on the same line as the command after the IF." and then it gives an almost identical example to the code above. As you say, par for the course in batch ;)

Comment: I've tried to make it a little clearer, though I've had a few beers this afternoon - I may have made it worse :-) You may want to check it.

Comment: I prefer the phrase "logical line" - which may be broken into several physical lines.