# else is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, dos

My code is:

```
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST D:\TestCMD\1.TXT GOTO 1

ELSE

ECHO NOT EXISTED FILE 1.TXT

:1

ECHO EXISTED 1.TXT
```

--> It work nomally but when i changed "1.txt" to "2.txt" --> It doesn't work and error: "else is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

```
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST D:\TestCMD\2.TXT GOTO 1

ELSE

ECHO NOT EXISTED FILE 1.TXT

:1

ECHO EXISTED 1.TXT
```

--> What's happen?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25073859/2861476) can help

Comment: Or reading `if /?` could also help

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['else' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365374/else-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score 1):

This syntax should help you:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF EXIST "D:\TestCMD\1.TXT" (
      ECHO EXISTED 1.TXT
  ) ELSE (
      ECHO NOT EXISTED FILE 1.TXT
)
pause
```