# Conditional IF function for Batch File

Tags: batch-file

Firstly this is a work around to another issue, but to not complicate this question I'll not go into what the original approach was.

Now I am trying to use a batch file to:

1. Read a text log file,
2. loop through to the penultimate line of the file
3. then do a conditional check to see if the last entry was a confirmation that a process had completed successfully or another message which would indicate it did not.
4. Based on the result of step 3 above, return the value of 0 for pass and 1 for fail so that SSIS can interpret the result.

The name of the text file is fed into the batch file as a parameter. 
Everything seems to work except for when I try to include an IF statement at which point it just doesn't return any result.

Can anybody advise what I'm doing wrong? - have tried to follow the guidance here: http://ss64.com/nt/if.html but clearly without success!

```
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in (%1) do (
    set "previous=!last!"
    set "last=%%x"
)
IF !last! == "EXPORT completed successfully" ECHO 1 ELSE ECHO 0
```

If the last line is changed to say ECHO !last! it correctly returns the string EXPORT completed successfully. I have tried the above code with & without quotes but to no success.

Any help would be appreciated as I've never had to use batch before.

Thanks

Comment: Replace `IF !last!` by `IF "!last!"` (remember that bith parts around the `==` are compared, including any surrounding `""`), and put `()` around `ECHO 1` (so that the command interpreter knows where to check for an `else` keyword), that's it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close! Note that I've added brackets around your IF and ELSE clauses. I've also added quotes around your `last`.

Finally, bear in mind that the whitespace around an IF...ELSE in batch is actually important - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365410/15393) for details.

```
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in (%1) do (
    set "previous=!last!"
    set "last=%%x"
)
IF "!last!" == "EXPORT completed successfully" (
    ECHO 1
) ELSE (
    ECHO 0 
)

ECHO !last!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you set a value in a command line using the `set` command, you should refer to this variable using `%`. For example:

```
@echo off
cls
:loop
rem DO SOMETHING
set /p userinp=Repeat (y,n)?
if "%userinp%" == "y" (goto loop)
pause
```

This batch does something and then asks a user if the procedure needs to be repeated using a `userinp` variable. Hope this helps.